# Git hub me pide credenciales al hacer push

Tags: git, github

Estoy trabajando con varios usuarios de github y yo soy el administrador para ello yo.

Tengo una cuenta en github, y esa cuenta es la que los demas usuarios suben sus avances, ya que este es el proyecto principal.

El incoveniente es que a pesar que en el usuario principal tengo registrada las llaves publicas de todos los usuarios, git les pide credenciales de acceso al hacer push o subir sus avances.

Habra alguna manera que git ya no solicite las credenciales?, pues ya están registradas en el usuario git principal

Comment: Tener un solo usuario sobre el cual multiples personas trabajan para llevar el control del trabajo no es de las mejores practicas. Si el problema es el limite de usuarios por un respositorio privado en Github, entonces recomendaria usar Bitbucket. Este permite tener multiples usuarios en respositorios privados.

Comment: Justamente estoy usando bickbucket pero me sale ese problema

Comment: tus usuarios tienen las llaves privadas en sus equipos?

Comment: El problema de ser "un único usuario" es que si uno de los colaboradores sube algo con bugs, después no es posible saber a quién echar la culpa :-) ya que en la historia de commits se verá siempre al mismo usuario. Lo que debes hacer es que cada colaborador tenga su propia cuenta en bitbucket. Tú compartes el repositorio con los demás, y así ellos lo verán también en su cuenta, pero usarán sus propias credenciales para acceder a él, y el log mostrará quién hace cada commit. El límite de usuarios con quien puedes compartir (gratis) es de 5.

Comment: Otra opción es que tú eres el dueño del repositorio y el único que puede hacer PUSH a él. Los demás tienen un "clon" del repositorio sobre el que sí pueden hacer PUSHEs, y cuando quieran que tú incorpores al repositorio "maestro" sus cambios, deben hacerte un "pull request" (que no es un comando git, sino algo que se hace a través de la interfaz de bitbucket y que hace que te llegue un mensaje). Si aceptas el pull request, bitbucket hará un pull del repositorio del colaborador, incorporando sus cambios al tuyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Como usar github

Tu creas el repositorio en github y que cada usuario descargue el repositorio, con un `git clone` :

```
git clone <url> <nombre-carpeta>
```

Dentro establecen su cuenta de usuario

```
git config user.name "paco"
git config user.email "paco@a.c"
```

se le saca el `--global` así cada usuario trabaja con su cuenta de forma local respecto al proyecto , de esta manera queda todo trazabilizado.

### ¿Porque usarlo así?

1. Tienes trazabilidad de qué usuario sube que. Si un usuario A , sube código que causa alguna incidencia , pues podrás ver que fue ese usuario , en caso contrario , como todos tienen el mismo usuario , no podrás ver que usuario sube que.
2. Puedes ver cuanto ha subido cada usuario, en que hilos ha trabajado. Obtener estadisticas de cada uno de sus casos.

## Conclusión

No es la mejor práctica a realizar si lo que tienes es una cuenta para varios usuarios, lo que tendría que hacer cada uno, sería crearse cada uno una cuenta de github o del repositorio que uses (bitbucket, gitlab, etc..)

Si usas de esa manera git, solo le estás aprovechando la opción de ramas y el historial de cambios , con su `log` que te da opción a volver atrás.

La solución que miro es esta, ya que en general no es la forma óptima de usar git , ya que es un poco *'alternativa'* de usarlo , es como tener un ferrari y usarlo para andar a 30km por hora.

Links que te pueden ayudar :

- [Establecer el usuario en git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)
- [Clonar un repositorio](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/)
- [Como funciona git](http://codigoofuscado.com/2017/12/11/una-breve-guia-de-como-funciona-git/)
- [Como trabajar con git](http://codigoofuscado.com/2017/12/11/una-breve-guia-de-como-funciona-git/)
- [Como trabajar con branch en git](http://codigoofuscado.com/2017/12/11/una-breve-guia-de-como-funciona-git/)

Comment: me funciono, Gracias,Lo realize tal como lo describes y funciono

Comment: Siempre ayudamos en la medida de lo posible. ^^