# Error al hacer git push GitLab - Rama protegida

Tags: git, git-push, gitlab

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema al momento de realizar un `git push`.

Mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verifico con `git config --list` si tengo la configuracion como el correo y el usuario y estan bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Envio la cadena de comando `git push origin main`, sale un mensaje de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago consulta con un `git status`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy haciendo desde Windows 10

PD: Ya revise varios link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

[Git hub me pide credenciales al hacer push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169007/git-hub-me-pide-credenciales-al-hacer-push)

[Problema al hacer git push](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291672/problema-al-hacer-git-push)

Comment: github es una cosa, gitlab es otra cosa. Igual, el primer error es muy claro: esa rama no permite que le hagas push directo. Si están usando git flow, significa que el dueño del repositorio quiere que hagas una rama nueva y hagas un Merge Request con tus cambios, en vez de ponerlos directo en la rama main, que es la que seguro tiene la versión estable

Comment: Revisa este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318599/git-push-error-pre-receive-hook-declined aunque básicamente lo que dice es lo que ya ha comentado @Alfabravo, que la rama estará protegida y no permite subida directa a ella. Si es tu proyecto puede ser que por defecto al crear el repositorio `GitLab` crea la rama `master` protegida ya de base

Answer (score 1):

El error es porque estas intentando hacer un push a una rama protegida, en caso de que seas el dueño del repositorio o que tengas acceso a las configuraciones debes quitarse la protección a esa rama en las configuraciones de las ramas del repositorio como lo muestra la siguiente imagen:
Entras al repo, vas a configuración> repositorio> ramas protegidas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionar la rama protegida y sacarle la protección, de lo contrario como dice AlfaBravo debes hacer el push a una rama habilitada para hacerlo o contactar al administrador del repositorio